Losing memory with Pyspark
I'm trying to write some code to do image clustering with pyspark. As part of this, I want to pull batches of images to throw into an incremental PCA model, but am running into memory issues that I don't really understand. I was trying to find how many images I could fit into a batch based on how much memory was remaining, but the estimated batch size is drastically larger than I can retrieve before either getting a "connection refused" error or the python kernel (in jupyter) crashes entirely.
A minimal example I was able to have reproduce the issue is as follows:
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from psutil import virtual_memory
import numpy as np

conf = SparkConf().set('spark.driver.memory', '2g')
conf = conf.set('spark.executor.memory', '1g')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

print('first:', virtual_memory().free/1000000, 'MB')
rdd = sc.parallelize(np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=(100, 700, 800, 3), dtype='uint8'))
print('second:', virtual_memory().free/1000000, 'MB')
vals = rdd.take(50)
print('third:', virtual_memory().free/1000000, 'MB')

The memory values fluctuate a little because background processes, I assume, but in general I'm getting returns like:
first: 2157.563904 MB
second: 1967.8208 MB
third: 1172.652032 MB

Now because the values generated for this are only uint8, I would expect the size of vals to be 84 MB (50*700*800*3*1 Byte), but between the creation of the RDD and the creation of vals, this reads as though I've lost closer to 800 MB. In general for the application I wrote, using rdd.take(50) would cost around 500 MB that I didn't ever seem to get back, with smaller values of the action losing less and flatlining at around 10 MB per image despite images being closer to 2 MB. Other actions like rdd.count were yielding similar results, with larger RDDs losing more memory than smaller ones.
I was initially assuming it had to do with RDDs being cached whenever an action is first called on them, but proceeding to call rdd.unpersist() had no effect on what was being displayed as free memory.
So what is occupying the memory that I can't account for, and how can I (if I can) get it released? Or am I just completely misunderstanding these memory values? I'm running into issues where I'm expecting to be able to collect around 400 images based on the outputted values, but the system crashes closer to 150.
Playing with spark.driver.memory didn't seem to have an effect, nor did spark.executor.memory.
